# What is exactly probability density?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am quite confused:

$$ f_x(x) = 4x^2 \text{ for } 0<x<1 \text{ else } f_x(x) = 0$$

Now for the equivalent probability mass function it's easy to see. On the X-axis we have the value of the random variable $X$ and on the Y-axis we have the corresponding probability of that exact value $p_{X_i}$

But this can't be the same for continuous random variables, because for example the function that I defined has for the value $x=1$ the value on the y-axis is $y=4*1^2 = 4 $; which can't be a probability because $4>1$. Now I understand that singletons have probability of zero for a continuous random variable, but still  I can't properly understand what is going on on the Y-axis in simple words in contrast with discrete random variables.

So how is the proper way of understanding what exactly is? I mean the probability has to do with the areas and the borders of those areas.

Comment: The values of a density function are not themselves probabilities.  Indeed, since this is a purely continuous distribution, the probability of observing a specified point is $0$.  Rather, the probability of observing a point in a measurable set $S$ is the integral of the density over $S$.  Note that $\int_0^1 4x^2\,dx>1$ so what you have written is not a probability density on $[0,1]$.

Comment: This is not a valid probability density. I think it should be $4x^{3}$. A probability density function is a function that when integrated over a set , gives you the probability of the random variable taking a value in that set. This is a very rough way of explaining and should be taken with a grain of salt . So integrating over $(0,1)$ you should get back $1$.

Comment: At most points, $f_X(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{P(X \in [x-h,x+h])}{2h}$. In this problem this fails at $0$ and $1$ and nowhere else.

Comment: You can think of the density function giving the probability mass for very small intervals. $\Pr(x \leq X < x + \mathrm{d}x) = f(x) \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Another possible pdf $f_X(x)=3x^2\cdot \mathbb I_{(0,1)}$

Answer (score 1):

By your question I assume that you are in a introductory course to probability. So I will keep it as simple as possible

A valid probability density function is just a non-negative Real valued Integrable(take Riemann integrable for simplicity) function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=1$ .

Such a function $f$ is said to be the pdf of a continuous rv $X$ if $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=P(X\in [a,b])=P(a\leq X\leq b)$. Note that the interval can be $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b]$ also .

Now you can easily see that $f(x)=\begin{cases} 4x^{3}\,,0<x<1\\ 0,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ . Satisfies that it is non-negative and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0} 0\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}4x^{2}\,dx+\int_{1}^{\infty} 0\,dx = 1$ . So this is a valid PDF.

If you want to think in terms of probability. Let $X$ be a uniform$[0,1]$ random variable.

So if $Y=\sqrt[4]{X}$ . Then $Y$ is also a random variable.

So this $Y$ will have the pdf $4y^{3}\,,0<y<1 $ and $0$ elsewhere.

That is for this particular pdf $f$. $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ represents the probability of picking a number
$x$ uniformly and randomly from $[0,1]$ such that $a\leq\sqrt[4]{x}\leq b$ .

In words , given $a$ and $b$. $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ is the probability that the fourth root of a uniformly and randomly chosen number from $[0,1]$ is greater than equal to $a$ and less than equal to $b$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: You can mark as answer any one of them so that this question thread is complete

Answer (score 1):

The formal definition of probability density is through Radon–Nikodym theorem. But I think that's not what you are looking for based on the description of this question.

To give a quick insight of probability density, let's focus on the word "density".

Say if you have a rock in hand, how would you describe "how large the stone is?"
Maybe you would say

> "the size is $2\mathrm{m}^{3}$"

or

> "the weight is bout $2\mathrm{t}$"

which corresponds to *volume* and *mass* in physics. These are two *measures* to describe how large the stone is. In physics, $\textit{density}=\textit{mass}/\textit{volume}$, so what density does is **telling us how to link these two measures**.

Now return to mathematics world, suppose you are asked how large a interval
$[a,b]$ is, you can tell him

> the length of this interval is $b-a$

or

> the probability of random variable $X$ falling into this interval is $p$

which corresponds to *Lebesgue measure* and (induced) *probability measure*,
what probability density does is nothing but building a bridge between these two measures. That's why we call this $f$ a density, the intuition behind it is exactly the same as the original concept in physics.

Comment: So in the case of discrete probability it is the chance of that event happening and for probability density the chance of an event happening is given by the interval $[a,b]$ times the probability density over that interval. In that sense $ P_i = \overline{p_i} * |[a,b]| $, but since in the discrete case $|[a,b]| = 1$ this makes $P_i = \overline{p_i}$